# How to integrate Google Tag Manager with a React App?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-tag-manager

The technical specifications for this projects is ExpressJS & ReactJS.
This is used as an Browser Extension.
I am using 'react-gtm-module' for implementing Google Tag Manager.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Landingpage from "./components/Landingpage.js";
import Landingpagetest from "./components/Landingpagetest.js";
import Ad from "./components/Ad.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module';
import Referral from "./components/Referral";
import OnInstall from "./components/OnInstall";

const tagManagerArgs = {
  gtmId: 'GTM-P5Q5Q84'
}
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/"></Route>
          <Route path="/tabbing" component={Landingpage} />
          <Route path="/test" component={Landingpagetest} />
          <Route path="/ads" component={Ad} />
          <Route path="/:id" component={Referral} />
          <Route path="/oninstall" component={OnInstall} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

So after adding the tag-manager its expected to fire the tag manager on this url [OpenTabs Extension](https://app.opentabs.org/tabbing).
However the tag manager doesn't fires on this page, checked using `Tag Assistant Legacy(by Google)`
The tag manager starts firing if I first hit the Record `Tag Assistant Legacy` on [OpenTabs Website](https://opentabs.org/), now If I hit Record for [OpenTabs Extension](https://app.opentabs.org/tabbing), the respective Tag shows up.

What is the implementation issue here?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to utilize the 'react-gtm-module' element within the componentDidMount() lifecycle method when using a class component due to the library's dependency on this lifecycle method.

```
class App extends Component {
 componentDidMount() {
   const tagManagerArgs = {
        gtmId: 'GTM-P5Q5Q84'
    }
    TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)
    } 
      render() {
        return ();
  }
}
```